# My Network Adaptor is present, but using the command 'lshw' shows that the 'device is not claimed'. How to claim this driver/device?

Tags: networking, wifi

I recently installed Linux Mint on my Dell Inspiron 3551 and everything works fine, except the WiFi network adaptor. I do not have an Ethernet port in my laptop and have to heavily rely on WiFi. Now I have tried to install the driver, and after using the command 'lspci' it shows that the network adaptor for WiFi is present. Yet 'lshw' shows that 'this device hasn't been claimed'. How do I claim this device? Or rather...how do I get my WiFi adaptor started?

I have used the following commands:

```
lshw -c net
 *-network UNCLAIMED

       description: Network controller
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0600000-d067ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 00:60:6e:01:01:b8
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=MOSCHIP usb-ethernet driver driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=full firmware=MOSCHIP 7830/7832/7730 usb-NET ip=192.168.1.102 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

sudo lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 49152  0 
mcs7830                16384  0 
usbnet                 45056  1 mcs7830
mii                    16384  2 mcs7830,usbnet
cmac                   16384  0 
rfcomm                 69632  8 
bnep                   20480  2 
dell_wmi               16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            20480  0 
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
intel_rapl             20480  0 
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0 
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       16384  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
kvm_intel             167936  0 
ath9k                 143360  0 
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
kvm                   532480  1 kvm_intel
dm_multipath           24576  0 
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_intel_sst_acpi     16384  0 
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0 
snd_intel_sst_core     73728  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
uvcvideo               90112  0 
snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform    90112  1 snd_intel_sst_core
dell_led               16384  1 
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
mac80211              733184  1 ath9k
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
videodev              180224  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform
snd_hda_intel          36864  5 
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
ath3k                  20480  0 
btusb                  45056  0 
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
punit_atom_debug       16384  0 
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
cryptd                 20480  0 
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
cfg80211              561152  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
bluetooth             516096  26 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
snd_pcm               106496  9 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
joydev                 20480  0 
input_leds             16384  0 
serio_raw              16384  0 
binfmt_misc            20480  1 
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
dw_dmac                16384  0 
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
mei_txe                20480  0 
mei                   102400  1 mei_txe
i2c_hid                20480  0 
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
snd                    81920  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
lpc_ich                24576  0 
shpchp                 36864  0 
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1 
soundcore              16384  1 snd
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0 
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0 
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0 
rfkill_gpio            16384  0 
8250_dw                16384  0 
pwm_lpss_platform      16384  0 
pwm_lpss               16384  1 pwm_lpss_platform
mac_hid                16384  0 
dell_rbtn              16384  0 
parport_pc             36864  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
dm_mirror              24576  0 
dm_region_hash         20480  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
i915                 1204224  7 
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        139264  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               122880  0 
drm                   360448  7 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  2 dell_led,dell_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,dell_laptop
fjes                   28672  0 
sdhci_acpi             16384  0 
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
```

iwconfig:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

lo        no wireless extensions.

dmesg| grep ath:

```
[    0.300659]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[    0.300662]  [] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[    0.422470]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[    0.422479]  [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[   19.182258] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   19.412748] device-mapper: multipath: version 1.10.0 loaded
[   19.567709] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   19.567872] ath: phy0: WB335 2-ANT card detected
[   19.567880] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   19.567902] ath: phy0: Mac Chip Rev 0xfffc0.f is not supported by this driver
[   19.567909] ath: phy0: Unable to initialize hardware; initialization status: -95
[   19.567918] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[   19.568108] ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -95
```

Comment: Post the result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: I ran the command you gave... it gave this:       03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:020e]

Comment: What Linux Mint version?  Driver from where?

Comment: I'm not sure where the driver is from (most probably pre-installed since i had windows in my laptop earlier). The Linux mint version is 17.3 Linux mint Rosa

Comment: What happens when you `sudo modprobe -v ath9k`

Comment: no result at all

Comment: Edit your question to add results of `lshw -c net; lsmod; iwconfig`

Comment: Driver is loaded but still shows unclaimed, post `modprobe -c | grep -i 020e; modinfo ndiswrapper`

Comment: result for modprobe -c| grep -i 020e:   alias hid:b0003g*v000005ACp0000020E hid_apple
alias pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001028sd0000020Ebc*sc*i* ath9k
alias usb:v05ACp020Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic03isc*ip02in* appletouch    result for modinfo ndiswrapper: modinfo: ERROR: Module ndiswrapper not found.

Comment: Please edit question to add `dmesg | grep ath`  Please use < pre >< code > before the output and </ pre> </ code> after without the spaces as it will preserve the format of the output

Comment: Did the same problem exist with the 3.19 kernel?  Can you access the wifi card to see if it is properly in the slot and if everything is clean?

Comment: I installed Linux just a day ago... I was working with windows before this

Comment: I would try a complete shutdown and then restart can you do `dmesg > dmesg.txt` then upload the contents of dmesg.txt to pastebin.com and post the URL

Comment: Here is the file dmesg.txt ... link: http://pastebin.com/Jk7591p9

Comment: Some weird things there, I would start with a BIOS update.  The Dell site shows a new version was released 5 months ago.  Also check for an IOMMU setting in the BIOS

Answer (score 1):

The kernel module (ath9k) or the firmware required by the wifi card is missing.
A fairly recent kernel should have this module with support for your wifi card.

`modinfo ath9k` will show if the kernel can provide info about this module.

`find /lib -name ath9k.ko` shows us if the module is anywhere on the disk.

Comment: result for modinfo atk9k:        filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     F7E3AF932B15681132EA595
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001028sd0000020Ebc*sc*i*
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-13-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)

Comment: and for find command there was no result

Comment: modinfo show the module is pressent in /lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko so find should also reveal this. The problem here seems to be that you are missing aliases which prevents you're system to detect that it should loat that module. A propper output is more like this: http://hastebin.com/juvikadohi
Try to also run a `depmod -a` before `modinfo ath9k` and `modprobe -v ath9k`.

Comment: the modinfo showed all aliases...i couldnt paste them all in the comment